# Problem building asp.net webform project in Azure Devops which uses devexpress

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-devops, devexpress

Currently I've been working to setup automation on asp.net web forms in azure devops. Since my source is on azure devops repository when trying to run a build, it gives an error as follows..

```
The type or namespace name 'DevExpress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The problem is with Devexpress dll package which dlls are pointing into a location which azure couldnt find.

Here are my attempts

1. Tried creating a new folder called dll references and added my devexpress dlls there, referred these dll by replacing previous devexpress dll references. Verified by looking into .csproj file. (Visual studio builds it completely without error but azure devops build agent wont)
2. Gone through the support ticket https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T728032/devexpress-issue-while-building-the-solution-on-azure-devops-vsts
   which suggests to use assembly deployment tool but this is not workable as it doesnt support for VS professional version.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: This is my hintpath code in .csproj file for your cue.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.Charts.v18.2.Core, Version=18.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>..\dll_references\DevExpress.Charts.v18.2.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: On your first attempt, have you add the new folder into the source control? If not, please try to add it to the source control and check if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for input. have created new folder in source control and made my devexpress available there and references been added too. Still the same :(